# Can't resolve nuxt plugin axios

Tags: nuxt.js

I am getting these errors when `npm run dev` using "nuxt": "^2.14.6",:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nuxt_plugin_axios_2cfed14d' in 'D:\XXX\YYY\dist'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nuxt_plugin_index_d9efdfe4' in 'D:\XXX\YYY\dist'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nuxt_plugin_plugin_2dba23ac' in 'D:\XXX\YYY\dist'
```

Any ideas how to fix? I tried to reinstall all packages, install these missing packages but none of them helped. Important note: sometimes it just works, sometimes not

Comment: Can you share some of your configuration?